# I am trying to test the REST Service in salesforce

Tags: rest

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {

    @HttpDelete
    global static void doDelete() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Account account = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
        delete account;
    }

    @HttpGet
    global static Account doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Account result = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
        return result;
    }

  @HttpPost
    global static String doPost(String name,
        String phone, String website) {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name = name;
        account.phone = phone;
        account.website = website;
        insert account;
        return account.Id;
    }
}
```

Host Name https://na34.salesforce.com

uri (which is needed to be shared with cross functional team)  https://na34.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account

I am getting error as " The content you are trying to view cannot be xml

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where the error is being reported, but assuming it is from an external client it looks like your `MyRestResource` is returning XML but the client expects JSON.

You can ensure a JSON response by getting the client-side code to set an "Accept" header of "application/json" or to append ".json" to the URL.